# How to check for number range (1-12) and not empty REGEX

Tags: javascript, regex

I currently have the following regex **`/^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])$/`** Which checks for numbers between 1 and 12. I also need to to check for empty aswell.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Your regex already doesn't allow empty strings.

Comment: Title says `How to check for number range (1-12) and not empty REGEX` but it seems OP wants to allow for empty strings.

Answer (score 2):

`/^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])?$/` will match empty strings as well. You're basically wrapping your whole regex with the conditional (`?`) operator.

Comment: Or did I misunderstand the question? If you're asking for a string that does **not** allow empty strings, then @anubhava's comment is correct.

Comment: Yes I also asked this question in my comment to OP. It seems OP wrote `not empty` in title but may want empty string to allow.

Comment: Strange, it seems to be allowing empty strings in my application, but I want it to not accept an empty string. Is my regex still wrong?

Comment: No, your regex should be fine. The only difference between ours is that mine will accept empty strings. Does yours not work?

Comment: it accepts any number between 1 and 12, and also accepts empty strings too, using javascript, does that make a difference?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lmr5yq8q/ - Works for me. I don't think that this is your problem.